# How to change the subject of email in mailable class in laravel

Tags: laravel

How to change the subject of email in mailable class in laravel 6. The subject on email showing is 'Send Email'. email is sending properly. the only problem is I am not able to change the subject of the email.

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class SendEmail extends Mailable
{
 use Queueable, SerializesModels;

protected $user;

  public function __construct($user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}

public function build()
{
    return $this->view('mails.verify_account')->with([
        'email_token' => $this->user->email_token,    
    ]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `subject` method:

```php
public function build()
{
    return $this->subject('Your subject')
        ->view('mails.verify_account')
        ->with([
            'email_token' => $this->user->email_token,    
        ]);
}
```

Check [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mail#writing-mailables) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

in your `__construct`, add: `$this->subject('bla bla');`